# Efficiently extracting a few values from several large Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several (tens to hundreds) DataFrames that I'm reading from .tab/.csv files. The DFs are substantial (thousands of rows, hundreds of columns, tens of MBs), but I only need to pick out just a couple of values from each DataFrame.

This is straightforward enough to do by looping through the files and extracting the needed values from each:

```
values = []

for file in datalist:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)

    # Identify values by row/column labels as positions may change
    val0 = df.loc['row_index_0', 'column_number_0']
    val1 = df.loc['row_index_1', 'column_number_1']
    val2 = df.loc['row_index_2', 'column_number_2']

    values.append([val0, val1, val2])
```

But I'm wondering if I need to worry about doing it *efficiently*, and if so, how best to do that. Like, do I need to worry about a simple `for` loop like that creating a bunch of sizeable `df` objects that then float around taking up memory?

And if that's a potential problem, what can I do to make sure the `df` objects are purged once no longer needed? Is there a simple context manager approach like using `with` statements?

Comment: What type of data are you working with? Integers or floats are handled by native types while strings and dates and things may be in more expensive python objects.

Comment: Mostly floats, with strings for index/column labels

Answer (score 3):

You cannot avoid iterating through all the csv files, but you can make it more efficient by not reading the entirety of each file into a dataframe.  If you are only interested in the first few (e.g. 3) rows and columns, then just read those as demonstrated here:

```
values = []

for file in datalist:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, nrows=3, usecols=[0,1,2])
    val0, val1, val2 = df.iloc[r0, c0], df.iloc[r1, c1], df.iloc[r2, c2]
    values.append([val0, val1, val2])
```

Comment: Thanks @pakpe - the issue is I don't necessarily know beforehand exactly which rows / columns I will need and will usually get them by label - the example was just placeholders; I've edited it to reflect that more clearly. So unless there's a way to read in part of the CSV by label rather than by position, this won't be reliable...

Comment: There may be a way. Provide an example of how the target rows and columns are specified in the label.

Comment: A tweak would be `pd.read_csv(file, usecols=[c0, c1, c2], index_col="whatever its name is")`. Also, `del df` at the end of the loop so that you don't have two df's in memory at the same time. This would still read all of the file but its mostly in C with native data types.

Comment: @pakpe Edited the example again, not sure if that's what you mean? usually just with string labels of the index and column (sometimes numeric where it's years but I have no need to convert to actual datetime)